# Code that sends it own http URL

Tags: upload, ftp

I have a website which has many clients. I am using FTP to give them the access right now to the folders to which they are concerned. Means that person "X" will be able to access ONLY the folder "X" with his FTP credentials. The thing is that now when my clients upload something via FTP then they are not able to know it's actual "http://" URL and therefore I have to tell them everything (for eg: http://example.com/clients/x/uploaded_file_name)

My clients use Filezilla and they say that there is no way to know the other folder name apart from "X" and thus they can't know the full URL and therefore also can't access it via browser. So I want to know that is it somehow possible that when somebody upload something via ftp (filezilla) then it's proper and full "http://" URL should be sent to some email address or somehow given to the client? Thanks a lot if you can let me know that how can it be done.

Comment: Can you describe a bit more what is happening in your server code and how it is structured at the moment?

Comment: @norlesh The flow is like this --> there are 100 clients, each have 1 folder assigned to them. This 1 folder of each person is inside 4-5 directories. So the http URL as of now would be likes this `http://www.example.com/my/users/clients/folders/1` Here `1` is the folder name of each client. Each client is upload something to their own folder, now I want that somehow the proper `http` URL of the uploaded file should be sent to the uploader(client). Also note that the directories in example URL that I gave are not known to any client.

Answer (score 0):

You could run some sort of background process on your server using system commands *[[such as inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) if you are running linux]* to check for folder writes.

Then call a script to calculate a relevant URL for the owner and email it to them based on user information and full path knowledge at this point.

Comment: could you please tell me/give me the script/code that I can use.

Comment: No, sorry - firstly I am writing this from a Windows machine so couldn't run and test it. secondly that is for you to do as a programmer or else find a suitable programmer to do it for you. StackOverflow is just here to provide specific code advice, not to write peoples code for them.